# MVVM Windows Phone using Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, mvvm, asp.net-web-api

I try to create MVVM Windows Phone App which consumes Web Api to retreive data from the server.

I make calls to Web Api from ViewModel classes and its perfect.
But I wonder if its possible that when data is updated from different client -> for example from Windwos desktop app, to then update automatically model in my Windows Phone App ?

Second problem is that I cant reference non Windwos Phone projects so that I have to create separate model classes inside my Windows Phone project.

What is the best way to have common model for each project ?

Thank You very much for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As about

> But I wonder if its possible that when data is updated from different client -> for example from Windwos desktop app, to then update automatically model in my Windows Phone App ?

Yes you can take a look at [Raw Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202977%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Meanwhile

> What is the best way to have common model for each project ?

As TomTom was saying Portabe Class Library is the way to have common code in different projects.